# Error when reading excel files using tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am currently using tkinter to get a User to select a .xlsx file. but I keep getting the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 18: character maps to 
<undefined>
```

Here is my code below. I have read that encoding="utf-8" should do the trick but unfortunately it won't work for me.
Can someone point out where I'm going wrong (I have imported .txt files in the past without any issues)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
 
from tkinter import *
  
# import filedialog module
from tkinter import filedialog


def your_script(dir1):
    df = pd.read_excel(dir1, encoding="utf-8")

    
    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'Desktop\Testing_GUI\testFile.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

    # Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Testing Tab',index=False)


    # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
    writer.save()
       
dir1 = filedialog.askopenfile(mode="r", initialdir="/", title="select file",
                                       filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"), ("all files", "*.*")))

your_script(dir1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer for this.
I found that changing mode from **mode = 'r'** to **mode='rb'** worked.

```
dir1 = filedialog.askopenfile(mode="rb", initialdir="/", title="select file",
                                       filetypes=(("text files", "*.txt"), ("all files","*.*")))
```